# Disable Java primitives wrapping in Rhino - Create java int

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, primitive, primitive-types

I'm trying to get some flow running in HP Operation Orchestrator, which implements Rhino engine for scripting.
The method failing is read,from InputStream object.

Per reference :
`int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`

### Javascript running in Rhino

```
var tmp = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.Byte,java.lang.Integer(1024));
while (true) {
  while (is.available() > 0) {
    i = is.read(tmp, java.lang.Integer(0), java.lang.Integer(1024));
  }
}
```

### Exception

InternalError: Can't find method
java.io.InputStream.read([Ljava.lang.Byte;,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer) (#62)

### Questions

1. Is it possible to force Rhino to create an int object?

My guess is I need to create pure (primitive) int objects in Rhino.
Not number, not Integers.
Per my tests, Rhino always convert any instance of int into number:

`js>typeof parseInt(3) number`

3. If not possible, Can I disable java primitives wrapping from RUNTIME ?

I tried this with no luck:

```
 var Context = org.mozilla.javascript.Context,
      currentContext = Context.getCurrentContext();
    Context.enter().getWrapFactory().setJavaPrimitiveWrap(false);
```

Comment: Sorry about the untag.... missed the rhino part when I first scanned it.

Comment: That is because `Byte[]` is not compatible with `byte[]`. It has nothing to do with `Integer` vs `int`. Try using [`java.lang.Byte.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#TYPE), for the primitive type `byte`.

Comment: That solved the issue!
The modified line is:

`tmp = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.Byte.TYPE, java.lang.Integer(1024));`

 Thanks Andreas.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas ...this helped us solve a bugging issue